# Memory issues with VMware fusion 8.5 on Apple Xserve

Tags: windows-10, memory, vmware-fusion

I am using VMware 8.5.10 on an Apple XServe to virtualise a Windows 10 Pro guest. This server has 48GB of RAM and 12 cores (dual 6-core CPUs) and two SSD drives (Samsung 860 Pro 480GB) on RAID mirror. macOS version is EL Capitan.

I have allocated 20GB of RAM on Windows and 4 CPU cores. This windows VM is running an SQLexpress server.

I am experiencing issues with the memory and specifically VMware eating up the host memory leaving it with approximately 400MB to 5GB free RAM.

I have disabled 3d acceleration on the VM, I have disabled disk buffering, I have registered the VM disk as SCSI with virtualSSD on and I have set the pagefile of windows to the recommended value. Windows installation is up to date.

The host machine is running the OsiriX MD server, a unifi controller and cleanmymac app on the background.

Activity monitor is reporting that the most memory consuming apps are Vmware fusion, VMware-vmx and WindowServer daemon. There is almost 20GB of cached files, again shown in the activity monitor.

I have tried to upgrade to VMware 10 but the problems got worse, especially on the VM side, due to CPU incompatibilities.

Any suggestions on how to resolve the memory issues? Anyone with a similar experience? What could be the cause of VMware eating up the host memory? There is no dynamic allocation whatsoever.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.